# Too much context switches - how to be sure that it is actual problem?

Tags: linux, scheduler, perf, context-switch

I suspect that my application suffers from too much context switches. There is huge amount of threads (do not ask why) and I wonder whether overhead related to switching context becomes problematic. My question here is:

1. How to know for sure that there is actually too much context switches? I can use `perf sched`.
2. You know, even if there is 10k threads it does not mean that every thread needs CPU in given quantom of time (because of being blocked on I/O / lock). But, is it possible in general way to know how time my threads are actually wait for CPU?

Comment: `uptime` will show the system-wide load average, but that includes tasks blocked on I/O as well as runnable.  For context switches per second system-wide, that's something you can monitor with `vmstat 1` (or whatever other interval between lines of output); look at the `cs` column.  Similar tools like `dstat` have nicer output.

Comment: @PeterCordes, thanks. But, how to know that it is too much context switches? Too much for me means: overhead incurred from context-switches causes performance degradation.